# Dependency Property Not Updating Visual Studio Designer

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, dependency-properties

I've created a style for a new WPF Window class and have some dependency properties on there. The one to note is

> ShowHelpButton

This is supposed to toggle the visibility of the Help button on the window. The code works fine in runtime, but I cannot get it to update the UI in the design view.

Here's the class:

```
public class MainWindowFrame : Window
{
  #region DependencyProperties

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowHelpButtonProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
     "ShowHelpButton", typeof (bool), typeof (MainWindowFrame), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

  public bool ShowHelpButton
  {
     get { return (bool) GetValue(ShowHelpButtonProperty); }
     set { SetValue(ShowHelpButtonProperty, value); }
  }

  #endregion


  static MainWindowFrame()
  {
     DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MainWindowFrame),
         new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MainWindowFrame)));
  }
```

Here's the Style:

```
<Style x:Key="MainWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type abstractClasses:MainWindowFrame}">
  <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
  <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
  <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LightBlueBrush}" />
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BlueBrush}" />
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
  <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="1" />
  <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize" />
  <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None" />
  <Setter Property="Title" Value="New Window" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
     <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type abstractClasses:MainWindowFrame}">
           <Border
              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
              CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}">
              <Grid x:Name="ContainerGrid" Background="Transparent">
                 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                 <Grid.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.Loaded">
                       <BeginStoryboard>
                          <Storyboard>
                             <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                From="0"
                                To="1"
                                Duration="00:00:01" />
                          </Storyboard>
                       </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                 </Grid.Triggers>
                 <Grid Background="Transparent" MouseDown="Window_MouseDownDrag">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                       <TextBlock
                          Margin="10,3,0,3"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          Style="{StaticResource CustomTitleBarTextBlackB}"
                          Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Button
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Width="20"
                       Height="20"
                       Margin="0,0,5,0"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                       AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Help"
                       Style="{StaticResource HelpButtonStyle}"
                       Visibility="{TemplateBinding Property=ShowHelpButton,
                                                    Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}" />
                 </Grid>

                 <AdornerDecorator Grid.Row="1">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="WindowContent" />
                 </AdornerDecorator>
              </Grid>
           </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
```

And finally, here's how I'm using it:

```
<abstractClasses:MainWindowFrame
x:Class="Utils.UI.NewFeaturesDialog"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:abstractClasses="clr-namespace:Utils.AbstractClasses"
xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:Utils.UI"
xmlns:utilResx="clr-namespace:Utils.Resources"
Width="775"
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
ShowHelpButton="False"
SizeToContent="Height"
Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MainWindowStyle}">

<Window.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
         <ResourceDictionary Source="/Utils;component/WPFStyles/Styles.xaml"/>
     </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
</abstractClasses:MainWindowFrame>
```

I've seemingly tried everything. I've added all the FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions by doing this:

```
FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange |

FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure |

FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender |

FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentMeasure |

FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentArrange
```

I've also added a callback to no avail. I've even tried restarting Visual Studio 2015. I'm starting to think it's just a VS bug, but I'm hoping someone has some idea of what's going on. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try to use trigger in controltemplate instead templatebinding and see whether it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated answer**

It looks like its a known design-time bug; for subclassed/derived Window objects
This reported bug seems to be related to this issue: [WPF designer not showing content assigned to custom DependencyProperty](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/770067/wpf-designer-not-sho)

> We cannot create a design instance of Window within the designer so we substitute with a proxy type of our own.

So if the designer can't create an instance of derived window type; the binding (TemplateBinding) logic will fail during design-time.

As it is not easy to provide fallback values to TemplateBinding, you can maybe use this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1793611/7292772) to provide default values to act as design-time behavior.

Comment: This has nothing to do with DataContext. TemplateBinding is exactly for this

Comment: Agreed. Just went through your code again; I had missed the template binding. I will update my answer.

Comment: That's what I thought (and was afraid of haha). Thanks for confirming that it's a VS bug. I hope it's not actually the intended design as that one comment suggests. Maybe one day it'll get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't recreate your problem.

I go usually in a simpler but still complicated way. I put ViewModel in another assembly, so I would have no temptation to reference it from view. + To make everything stylable, I put Templates into Generic.xaml and override Styles in another dictionary, that is loaded after Generic in App.xaml
Here is how I do things.

MyWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Sandbox.MyWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sandbox"
    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:ProjectLibrary;assembly=ProjectLibrary"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DataContext="{DynamicResource DesignViewModel}"
    Title="MyWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <l:MyViewModel x:Key="DesignViewModel" SomeButtonVisibility="Collapsed"/>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeText}"/>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="1 Button"/>
    <Button Visibility="{Binding SomeButtonVisibility}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="2 Button"/>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="3 Button"/>
</StackPanel>
```

In App.xaml I remove StartupURI to handle it in App.xaml.cs:

```
using ProjectLibrary;
using System.Windows;

namespace Sandbox {
public partial class App : Application {
    MyWindow w;
    MyViewModel vm;

    public App() {
        w = new MyWindow();
        //You also can pass Action to open new window of some sort here
        //or other things, that VM can't have access to
        vm = new MyViewModel(true);
        w.DataContext = vm;

        w.Show();
    }
  }
}
```

MyViewModel:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace ProjectLibrary
{
public class MyViewModel : Notifiable
{
    public MyViewModel() :this(false) {
    }

    public MyViewModel(bool Execute) {
        if (Execute) {
            SomeText = "Execution data";
        } else {
            SomeText = "Design Data";
        }
        SomeButtonVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private string _someText;
    public string SomeText { get { return _someText; } set { _someText = value; RaisePropertyChanged("SomeText"); } }

    private Visibility _someButtonVisibility;
    public Visibility SomeButtonVisibility { get { return _someButtonVisibility; } set { _someButtonVisibility = value; RaisePropertyChanged("SomeButtonVisibility"); } }
 }
}
```

Notifiable.cs:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace PTR.PTRLib.Common {
public class Notifiable : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        // take a copy to prevent thread issues
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
 }
}
```

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="Sandbox.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sandbox">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Generic.xaml"/> <!-- Default Styles -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/StyleRes.xaml"/> <!-- ColorTemplates -->
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Templates/Generic.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sandbox">
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyWindow}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <AdornerDecorator>
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </AdornerDecorator>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResizeWithGrip">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource WindowTemplateKey}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Themes/StyleRes.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sandbox">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyWindow}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
</Style>
```

I'm not a professional in WPF, but this is what I learned in 1.5 year course of programming a database + wpf interface (nice one).

Comment: Aww... As Sharada Gururaj said it's a known bug. Now I remember that I dealt with something like that previously and found no solution. So I started doing everything in user controls, but now I realized that you can do CustomControls easily with my pattern. You can prototype every control as UserControl and then copy/paste and create a CustomControl. It will be easy to make templates and reuse your controls later.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This could possibly work as a workaround, but the only issue is that all the code to design MyWindow has to be done in a .cs file since I'd want to inherit MyWindow in another class that includes xaml code (you aren't allowed to inherit a class that was defined using xaml in another xaml file). I don't really want to create all my UI code in cs files.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be a short answer.... But I am thinking the issue, since it is only at design time, might be due to a data context issues in the designer. Have you tried d:DataContext?

```
 d:DataContext ="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type nameSpace:ViewModel}, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```

https://www.codeproject.com/tips/879109/using-design-time-databinding-while-developing-a-w